# Why does for every matrix norm $\lVert \mathbb{I } \rVert \geq 1$ hold?

Tags: matrices, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Why does for every matrix norm $\lVert \mathbb{\cdot }\lVert $

$$\lVert  \mathbb{I }  \rVert  \geq 1$$ hold (where $\mathbb{I }$ is the identity matrix)? I tried to prove it just by the definitions of a matrix norm but I didn't succeed. Can anybody help me?

Comment: $\|A B\|\le \|A\|\ \|B\|$?

Comment: I was going to say, they probably assume only sub-multiplicative norms.

Comment: $A = \mathbb{I}$ so, $\lVert  \mathbb{I}   \rVert   \lVert  B   \rVert \geq \lVert  \mathbb{I }  B \rVert$. What is B?

Comment: $B = A$... ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrix norms are usually defined to be submultiplicative (see for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixNorm.html)), that is for any two matrices $A, B$ such that $AB$ exists, we have 
$$ \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{AB} \le \norm A \norm B\tag{$*$} $$
Now, let's look at $\mathrm{id}$, as $\mathrm{id} \ne 0$, we have $\norm{\mathrm{id}} >0$ and, as $\mathrm{id}^2 = \mathrm{id}$ by ($*$), 
$$ \norm{\mathrm{id}} = \norm{\mathrm{id}^2} \le \norm{\mathrm{id}}^2 $$
Dividing by $\norm{\mathrm{id}}\ne 0$, gives $1 \le \norm{\mathrm{id}}$.